# Transaction in jboss eap JmsComponent camel context

Tags: jboss, transactions, apache-camel

I'm having troubles setting up transactions using JtaTransactionManager. I've tried everything I could find in internet.
I want to make rollback if there is any Exception in the route or in the routes coming from this route.

Here is my camel context beans:

```html
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:/JmsMQXA" />
            <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
            <property name="cache" value="true" />
            <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="jmsTransactionManager"           class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
            <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
  </bean> 
 <bean id="mq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
           <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
           <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />
           <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
   </bean>
<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" />
</bean>
```

My route:

```
<route>  
        <from uri="mq:TEST.QUEUE" /> 
                 <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
```

MY standalone

```html
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>...
```

And the problems I get:

```
WARN  [org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.QUEUE]) Transaction rollback (0x68e69794) redelivered(true) for (MessageId: ID:414d51205141424749434c4441202020ab7e795dfb630223 on ExchangeId: ID-M0AB1I4O-1572259802058-0-7) caught
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.QUEUE]) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4026:Transaction backed out with reason: 'The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '100'.'.
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.QUEUE]) ARJUNA016045: attempted rollback of < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0ae317d6:-21705625:5db6b586:1f48, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0ae317d6:-21705625:5db6b586:1f4c, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/JmsMQXA > (XAResourceWrapperImpl@258df727[xaResource=com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper@4e359608 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=WebSphere MQ productVersion=%I% %E% %U% jndiName=java:/JmsMQXA]) failed with exception code XAException.XAER_NOTA: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_rollback' has failed with errorCode '-4'.
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.rollback(JmqiXAResource.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper.rollback(XARWrapper.java:598)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.rollback(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:196)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelAbort(XAResourceRecord.java:362)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:3023)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:3002)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.Abort(BasicAction.java:1674)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.cancel(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:124)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.abort(AtomicAction.java:186)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.rollbackAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1371)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.rollback(BaseTransaction.java:143)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.rollback(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:134)
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.rollbackAndDissociate(LocalTransaction.java:104)
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.rollback(ContextTransactionManager.java:83)
    at org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalUserTransaction.rollback(LocalUserTransaction.java:58)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doRollback(JtaTransactionManager.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:857)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:717)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:249)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using wildfly-camel with EAP. That is recommended to use as they have done all the hard work of making it work well together.

Answer (score 0):

There was an older issue with WebSphere MQ, I can now only find quickly this reference https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250976 
Maybe it gives you a hint (and in any case, trace logs on the MQ server could show more info)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code snippet.  The JmsTransactionManager should not be assigned from the NDI transaction manager - which is a JTA transaction manager.  Note that if you set you component as 'transacted' and provide a connection factory, then Spring JMS will instantiate a JmsTransactionManager for you and wire it up to the connection factory. So, just:

```
 <bean id="mq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
       <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
       <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />
       <property name="receiveTimeout" value="100000"/>
```

And then drop:

```
 <bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
```

and:

```
<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" 
class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
<property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW" />
```

Maybe try something like:

```
<bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" id="source.mqConnectionFactory">
    <property name="connectionNameList" value="10.0.0.207(1414)"/>
    <property name="queueManager" value="MY.QUEUE.MANAGER"/>
    <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"/>
    <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
    <property name="clientReconnectOptions" value="67108864"/>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter" id="source.mqUserCred">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="source.mqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="my-password"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    id="source.pooledConnectionFactory" primary="true">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="1"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="0"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="source.mqUserCred"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" id="source">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="source.pooledConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
            <property name="receiveTimeout" value="100000"/>
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```